# ANTLR3 implemented Jaccard Similarity to compare two java's files

Tags: java, similarity

See this code, this is from JCCD API that I mashed up. ^_^

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getFile()));
    String filePath = f.getNama(); // getName of file
    final Antlr3JavaLexer lexer = new Antlr3JavaLexer();
    lexer.preserveWhitespacesAndComments = false;
    try {
        lexer.setCharStream(new ANTLRReaderStream(in));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }


    StringBuilder sbu = new StringBuilder();
    while (true) {
        org.antlr.runtime.Token token = lexer.nextToken();
        if (token.getType() == lexer.EOF) {
           break;
        }
        sbu.append(token.getType());
            System.out.println(token.getType());
    }
```

it gives me an output like this for TestFileOne.java

```
876116423877916429791644323742916418167432388167444266238816449164291643016743444242877916429791641179164432310329164351674323742916420164432316461643016444426623164616430164444242881644442879010116429164164224143234242[]
```

and this TestFileTwo.java

```
876116423877916429791644323742916418167432388167444266238816449164291643016743444242877916429791641179164432310329164351674323742916420164432316461643016444426623164616430164444242881644442879010116429164164224143234242[]
```

now my qusetion is, anyone can give me a clue or suggestion to implemented jaccard similiarity for the expected result like an output like percentage of the similiarity both ?
Thank you so much ...

Comment: Your question is not specific enough ("can anyone help" or "give a clue" rarely are a good fit for SO). Have you tried: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+jaccard

Comment: Mr Bart, perhaps can you give me an example ?